# SVNKIT=> SVNUpdateClient.doCheckout method - pegRevision?

Tags: java, svn, svnkit

I am using SVNKit to checkout svn base repository. Earlier I was using checkout to head for that purpose I was using SVNRevision.HEAD. It was working fine without issue.

below is the syntax of same and revision.Head was used in case of checkout to Head.

```
doCheckout(SVNURL url,File dstPath,SVNRevision pegRevision,SVNRevision revision, boolean recursive)
```

but let say if I have to checkout to a specific revision for example 27988, what should be value of pegRevision parameter ?

I am confused please help, I tried HEAD/BASE for pegrevision and also same 27988 etc but it gives error like URL not exist etc .

**Just an update,** problem was with my code revision was going as 0 always due to some logic issue hence SVN URL was not found and giving error. I tried now with HEAD as pegRevision and 27988 revision works just fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first, you have to specify an `SVNRevision`, not an integer.

```
long targetRev = 27988;
SVNRevision revision = SVNRevision.create( targetRev );
doCheckout(...
```

As for `pegRevision`, you almost certainly want `SVNRevision.HEAD`.  As the docs specify, it is:

> the revision at which `url` will be firstly seen in the repository to
>   make sure it's the one that is needed

So, HEAD is usually sufficient.  When it's not, things get complicated (and very specific), see the [svn book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.advanced.pegrevs.html).

Comment: thanks roippi for the reply I am aware that we need SVNRevision. but what confusing me is "the revision at which URL was firstly seen", so what I am doing is checking out complete trunk project on certain revision on which that project exist but inside files which belong to project might have added/deleted/modified.

Comment: Just an update, problem was with my code revision was going as 0 always due to some logic issue hence SVN URL was not found and giving error. I tried now with HEAD as pegRevision and 27988 revision works just fine. Thanks!